# Read a Wordpress HTML

Tags: html, wordpress

I have [an wordpress site](http://www.produtoimagem.com), with photolux as theme.

I want to read the HTML like the titles, the  tags, but it doesn't show it.

PS: I dont want to read the XML.

Any idea?

Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure that I understand your question.  Do you just want to View the HTML source?  If so, most browsers allow you to do so by going to View --> Source.

If that doesn't do the trick, you can use Developer Tools in Chrome or Firebug in Firefox to view the rendered content.

Comment: So, I'm doing that, but in the code, it dont show the main content, with the boxes (title/images). It just "skip" this code. Take a look. ;-) Thanks!

Comment: What browser are you in?  If you're using Chrome, use the Developer Tools on the page to see the rendered content.  If you are in Firefox, you can do the same with Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Chrome and the Developer tools (press F12) to see the content that is being generated by jQuery.

In Firefox you use the Firebug add-on.

Comment: That should do the trick.  If you're using Firefox, you can also use Firebug to do the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but Ryan answered this 24 minutes ago, and you 28! :-D

Answer (score 0):

use a different theme that doesn't suppress this content. The theme you have doesn't show the content you want. That isn't a very easy question to answer.

Comment: The content is being generated via AJAX and that's why is not in the source. It has nothing to do with the theme.